Question about quadratic convergence
I was reading through Nesterov's convex optimization lectures, and I noticed that in his analysis of Newton's method, he ends up with the relation
$$
r_{k + 1} \leq \frac{Mr_{k}^{2}}{2\left(\ell -Mr_{k}\right)}\quad
\mbox{as his}\ {\it recurrence\ relation}.
$$

However, I was under the impression that a quadratically convergent sequence satisfies
$r_{k + 1} \leq Cr_{k}^{2}$.
Is there a simple way in which I can explain
how this recurrence relation implies quadratic convergence ?.
Is there something missing ?.


Let $C=M/\ell$, and start with $r_0\leq\ell/(2M)$.
